# Why does clicking a QToolButton generate a leaveEvent? Is there a workaround?

Tags: qt

For some reason, whenever the menu-button part of the QToolButton gets clicked, it generates a momentary leaveEvent (at least when it is in a toolbar). I even tested underMouse() in the leaveEvent, and it returns false. Why is this? Is there a way to fix this?

Sample for testing (Py3.3, change super() for py2.7):

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        toolbar = QToolBar(self)
        toolbar.addWidget(ToolButton())

class ToolButton(QToolButton):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setText('test')
        self.setPopupMode(QToolButton.MenuButtonPopup)
        self.setMenu(QMenu())
        self.menu().addAction('Stub')

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        print('entered')
        super().enterEvent(event)

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        print('left')
        super().leaveEvent(event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    application = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

Comment: It seems to work fine for me. When I click menu button, leave event doesn't occur: http://i.imgur.com/uGniD7s.png It occurs only when I move mouse to the menu: http://i.imgur.com/r6ma0a8.png Does it work differently for you?

Comment: I don't quite see why you'd think it's a problem. Try listing the contents of the `event` and see what's there. Perhaps you can discriminate based on it.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov: Doesn't work for me. Maybe its the version? I'm using PyQt 4.10.1 Qt4.8.4 x64 with Py3.3.1 x64 with Win7

Comment: @KubaOber: I need to change the ToolButton paint/style depending on whether the mouse is over it or not. Currently, every time it gets clicked, there is a flash between the two versions.

Comment: Again, what are the contents of `event` when your undesired `leaveEvent` is called?

Comment: @KubaOber: `event.type()==11==QEvent.Leave`, `event.spontaneous() == False`. Its the same as a desired event. Is there something else I should be looking for? Those are the only contents I could find for a QEvent.

Answer (score 1):

The following can be used to double check; unlike leaveEvent, it always returns the correct information:

```
def leaveEvent(self, event):
    if not QApplication.widgetAt(QCursor().pos()) is self:
        #do stuff
    super().leaveEvent(event)
```